# How to deal with overfitting in Tensorflow?

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm currently trying to train a image classification convolutional neural network. I'm using an architecture similar to that in the TensorFlow tutorial. After training, I can get a quite high training accuracy and a very low cross entropy. But the test accuracy is always only a little bit higher than random guessing. The neural network seems to suffer from overfitting. In the training process, I have applied stochastic gradient descent and droupout to try to avoid overfitting. But it just doesn't seem to work.

Here is part of my code.

```
batch_image = np.ndarray(shape=(100,9216), dtype='float')
batch_class = np.ndarray(shape=(100,10), dtype='float')
# first convolutinal layer
w_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 3, 64])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([64])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 48, 64, 3])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, w_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
norm1 = tf.nn.lrn(tf.to_float(h_pool1, name='ToFloat'), 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75)

# second convolutional layer
w_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 64, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(norm1, w_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
norm2 = tf.nn.lrn(tf.to_float(h_pool2, name='ToFloat'), 4, bias=1.0, alpha=0.001 / 9.0, beta=0.75)

# densely connected layer
w_fc1 = weight_variable([12*16*64, 512])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([512])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(norm2, [-1, 12*16*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, w_fc1) + b_fc1)

#densely connected layer
w_fc2 = weight_variable([512, 256])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([256])
h_fc2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_fc1, w_fc2) + b_fc2)

# dropout
keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc2, keep_prob)

# readout layer
w_fc3 = weight_variable([256, 10])
b_fc3 = bias_variable([10])

y_prob = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, w_fc3) + b_fc3)

# train and evaluate the model

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_prob + 0.000000001))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_prob, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

for i in range(100):
  rand_idx = np.random.randint(17778, size=(100))
  k = 0
  for j in rand_idx:
    batch_image[k] = images[j]
    batch_class[k] = np.zeros(shape=(10))
    batch_class[k, classes[j, 0]] = 1.0
    k+=1

  train_step.run(feed_dict={x:batch_image, y_:batch_class, keep_prob:0.5})
  train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch_image, y_:batch_class, keep_prob:1.0})
  train_ce = cross_entropy.eval(feed_dict={x:batch_image, y_:batch_class, keep_prob:1.0})
```

I am wondering is there any mistake in my code or do I have to apply any other strategies to get a better test accuracy.

Thank you!

Comment: Reducing the size of your network, and augmenting the training data with random distortions of the training images are a few things to try. How large is your training data set?

Comment: @keveman The training data set consists of 17778 images. And I'll try your methods. Thank you!

Comment: I'm in the midst of learning dropout for CNN's.
can you post your solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below strategies to avoid overfitting.

1. shuffle the input data
2. Use early stopping for the Loss function with some Patience level.
3. L1 & L2 Regularization
4. Add Dropout
5. Batch Normalization.
6. If pixels are not normalized, dividing the pixels values with 255 also helps.
7. Perform Image Data Agumentation.
8. May be hyper parameter tuning grid search.

Hope it helps! Happy Coding.

Thank You!